# How to jump object using arrow key in p5js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

This is my code that I tried. The ball is jumping when I pressing "up arrow key" or "space bar".The problem is that I am unable to move ball little bit forward when ball jumped.Can anybody help me please?

```
let jumper;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    jumper = new Jumper();
}

function draw() {
    clear();
    jumper.run();

    push();
    fill(217);
    textFont('Avenir');
    textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
    textSize(33);
    text('space bar to jump', width>>1, height*0.15);
    pop();
}

function keyPressed() {
    jumper.vel.y = -4;
    jumper.vel.x=+5;
}
```

Comment: Can you please narrow your problem down to a [mcve]? We can't run this code. What do you mean when you say you're unable to move the ball a little bit forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up a very basic example of what I think you might be working towards:

```js
let jumper;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    jumper = new Jumper();
}

function draw() {
    clear();
    jumper.run();
 
    push();
    fill(217);
    textFont('Avenir');
    textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
    textSize(33);
    text('space bar to jump', width>>1, height*0.15);
    pop();
}

function keyPressed() {
    jumper.x+=5;
}

class Jumper {
  
  constructor() {
    this.x = 10;
    this.y = height/2;
  }
  
  run() {
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@0.10.2/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

@Dishant was correct in that your code had a typo in where you did `jumper.vel.x =+ 5` which is basically just setting the position of the jumper to the x position of 5. When what you want is to actually make the jumper move 5 pixels forward - in my example this done using `jumper.x += 5` but you'd of course use `jumper.vel.x += 5` as that code wasn't shown in your question!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the bug in the second last line.

```
jumper.vel.x += 5;
```